# Blockquote element for centered text in books

Tags: html, semantic-markup, blockquote

Once in a while, a novel (book, story, short story, etc.) will have a block of centered text to display something external from the main subject, either a sign that is being read, an abstract text, etc.

Would it be proper (semantically correct) to use the `blockquote` element in these cases? For example:

```css
section {
  width: 350px;
  font: 14px/1.3em Charter, sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

section>p+p {
  text-indent: 1.5em;
}

blockquote {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>I stepped back as far as I could and bent to peer under the door. There was nobody there; the stall must have been locked from the inside.</p>
  <p>Cursing, I lowered my face and saw a piece of wet paper lying on the floor in front of the stall. It must’ve been glued to the door and fallen off. It informed:</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Closed for maintenance.</p>
    <p>Sorry for any inconvenience.</p>
  </blockquote>
  <p>I fixed my eyes on the space between the floor and the door. It wasn’t so small, maybe […]</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes, it will be semantically correct